# exempt instance of html tag from formatting

Tags: html, css

If I have a linked style sheet that makes all `<ul>` elements to be formatted a certain way, then formatting in most instances of the `<ul>` would be correct - but not all.

Is there a way to exempt just one instance of an html tag from a linked stylesheet?

Comment: can you post any code?

Comment: Hi Diego, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I took the liberty of editing your question to make it a bit more readable, but it still needs some more work. Could you add some explanation of how you want most of the `<ul>` elements to be formatted, and what the exceptions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C` in CSS is for `cascade`, this means that every rule will be applied to every element that matches the selector and (depending on the rule nature) to its children. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Cascading_and_inheritance) you can read more about it.

That being said the only way to prevent for a rule to be applied is to override it with a more specific rule. In case of equally specific rules, the last one being defined wins (this applies to both rules in the same `.css` and rules in a different file).

Finally, you *can* stop inheritance with [the all property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand), but this could result in an unexpected behavior for its children if you (or somebody else) is not aware of this property being used.

Using `background` as an example property from the general formatting class `.general-element`, you have to override it with a more specific class (`.specific-element`):

```
.general-element {
  background: red;
}

.specific-element {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Nevertheless I think that the best way to deal with this cases is to make specific classes that **do** apply, this is achieved by defining specific classes instead of broad ones: **it is an antipattern to format every `<ul>` tag and you should avoid that**.

You don't want to be avoiding rules.